# How to update TFS cumulative flow every day

Tags: charts, tfs, kanban

In TFS 2017 Update 1 the cumulative flow chart is only updated every 7 days and looks like below. Is there any way to get it to update every day?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the Cumulative Flow chart is marked with 7 days intervals it will be dynamically updated as and when you change the work item states.

For example I have only one story active below out of 5 work items
[image]

Then I changed status of work items so that 1 is closed, 1 is new and other three active. The chart dynamically updates.
[image]

Comment: It seems that the current values are used for today and historical data is only updated every seven days.